# How do I get scanner input to register a blank space as a value

Tags: java

I am writing a code that represents an old-fashioned phone keypad. Everything is working fine except for when I try to take a blank space from the user which is supposed to print out the number 0. I've tried Unicode as well with '\u0020' but that didn't work either. In the output If I type a space and hit enter, I get another line so the scanner is not recognizing the blank space as a char that would be my guess. Someone, please help thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class phoneKeypad{

  public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Please enter a letter: ");
    char userInput = input.next().charAt(0);

    if (userInput == 'a' || userInput == 'b' || userInput == 'c' ||
            userInput == 'A' || userInput == 'B' || userInput == 'C')
    {       
        System.out.println(userInput + " is the number 2!");
    }
    else if (userInput == 'd' || userInput == 'e' || userInput == 'f' ||
                userInput == 'D' || userInput == 'E' || userInput == 'F')
    {       
        System.out.println(userInput + " is the number 3!");    
    }   
    else if (userInput == 'g' || userInput == 'h' || userInput == 'i' ||
                userInput == 'G' || userInput == 'H' || userInput == 'I')
    {           
        System.out.println(userInput + " is the number 4!");
    }
    else if (userInput == 'j' || userInput == 'k' || userInput == 'l' ||
                userInput == 'J' || userInput == 'K' || userInput == 'L')
    {           
        System.out.println(userInput + " is the number 5!");
    }
    else if (userInput == 'm' || userInput == 'n' || userInput == 'o' ||
                userInput == 'M' || userInput == 'N' || userInput == 'O')
    {           
        System.out.println(userInput + " is the number 6!");
    }
    else if (userInput == 'p' || userInput == 'q' || userInput == 'r' || userInput == 's' ||
                userInput == 'P' || userInput == 'Q' || userInput == 'R' || userInput == 'S')
    {           
        System.out.println(userInput + " is the number 7!");
    }
    else if (userInput == 't' || userInput == 'u' || userInput == 'v' ||
                userInput == 'T' || userInput == 'U' || userInput == 'V')
    {           
        System.out.println(userInput + " is the number 8!");
    }
    else if (userInput == 'w' || userInput == 'x' || userInput == 'y' || userInput == 'z' ||
                userInput == 'W' || userInput == 'X' || userInput == 'Y' || userInput == 'Z')
    {           
        System.out.println(userInput + " is the number 9!");
    }
    else if (userInput == '\u0020')
    {           
        System.out.println("Blank space is the number 0!");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println(userInput + " could be either a 1 or the character does not exist");
    }
    input.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
char userInput = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
```

instead of:

```
char userInput = input.next().charAt(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Scanner.nextLine() instead of next() :

```
char userInput = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

`scanner.nextLine()` will capture everything in the line, including whitespace.

`scanner.next()` will not capture whitespace as the delimiter is whitespace by default.

So, try using scanner.nextLine();

Comment: Thank you so much!